# Tapping into an existing electrical line

Tags: electrical, wiring

We've added a bedroom to our upstairs, and I am adding a run of outlets and a light switch for the new room. They are below a cable in the attic that I'm tapping into. I need jumpers on both ends of this cable I'm cutting. Here is my plan, I think should be pretty straightforward. Please let me know what you think. The pigtail connections will all be in a junction box, including the ground wire from the main line connected to the box's ground screw. And where the main cable cuts connect to the jumpers will also be in a junction box.
[image: wiring plan]

Comment: Is blue here for neutral instead of white because otherwise it is hard to draw? Or is this outside US/Canada with different colors in use? This is important to know because rules and best practices can vary around the world.

Comment: Is there any good reason you cannot add an additional circuit. This could eliminate a lot of potential problems in the future.

Comment: Yup, the blue is neutral

Comment: where does the OUT cable goes ?

Comment: What do the circles represent? What is a "jumper"? How is a light connected to light switch - is it new or pre-existing?

Answer (score 0):

ALL of the ground wires in a junction box need to be connected together, as well as a jumper grounding the box if metal boxes are used. You will clearly need to be using at least 2 boxes, unless the line being tapped has a very unusual amount of slack in it.